# C send dummy integer as reference pointer without a variable definition

Tags: c

I plan to call the function `test_func`.

One way is to define a variable and send its address like:

```
int dummy;
test_func(&dummy);
```

This works fine. But what if I decide to avoid a dummy variable definition? Such an implementation fails with a compiler error:

```
test_func(&int());
```

**main.c**  ~~~ [(onlinegdb)](https://onlinegdb.com/BJ84ODuYV)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int action(int *x)
{
    int error_code=0;
    *x=123;
    return error_code;
}

int test_func(int *x)
{
    if(action(x))
    {
        printf("success!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("failue!\n");
        return 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    test_func(&int());
    return 0;
}
```

How can I call this function in such a way?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do it. If a function takes a pointer argument, you need to give it a pointer to something. There are no temporary dummy pointers in C. I think C++ can do this, but not C.

Comment: If you don't want to provide a useful value, why not just use `NULL` and add proper checks?

Comment: @Gerhardh, De-referencing `NULL` is UB. Adding an `if` statement is an extra unnecessary check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's clearest to just use the variable, you can get what you're looking for with a [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html):

```
test_func(&(int){1});
```

Comment: for `C++` this yields an error `error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]` when compiling. Is there a way for C++?